# Error installing scipy package on Windows

Tags: python, windows, scipy, pip, installation

I was trying to install some specific packages for python2.7 on Windows using pip and got the following error while trying to install scipy 0.16.1:

```
(env) C:\Users\Asus\Documents\LEI\Algo-Rhythm>pip install --no-use-wheel scipy==0.16.1
DEPRECATION: --no-use-wheel is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Please use --no-binary :all: instead.
Collecting scipy==0.16.1
  Using cached scipy-0.16.1.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for scipy, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
Complete output from command c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\asus\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-itlx8i\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pip-uzs8w6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\include\site\python2.7\scipy:
lapack_opt_info:
openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\asus\\documents\\lei\\algo-rhythm\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\asus\\documents\\lei\\algo-rhythm\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:635: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\np-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.11.38-sse2-64\lib is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\asus\\documents\\lei\\algo-rhythm\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-itlx8i\scipy\setup.py", line 253, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-itlx8i\scipy\setup.py", line 250, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-itlx8i\scipy\setup.py", line 175, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\asus\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-itlx8i\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pip-uzs8w6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\asus\documents\lei\algo-rhythm\env\include\site\python2.7\scipy" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-itlx8i\scipy\
```

I think I'm missing some packages, but I'm struggling to understand this error. I used the no-use-wheel option because it was failling to build the wheels. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows you have to build Scipy from source.

The easiest way to get Scipy on windows is to use the anaconda package manager. It will automatically install Scipy and all of its dependencies.

https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: since v1.0 you can pip install or download from cgohlke's builds.